# How to run dotnet-counters as non root in Openshift?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, debian, openshift

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM my-private-docker-repo.net/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS base
FROM my-private-docker-repo.net/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace 
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-counters
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-dump

# build the app
FROM build AS publish
# publish the app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
COPY --from=build /root/.dotnet/tools/ /app/tools
ENV PATH="/app/tools:${PATH}"

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "something.dll"]
```

The image is built using docker and ran in private on-premises Openshift cluster.
Now, when I open container terminal in Openshift and type
`dotnet-counters ps` says "Permission denied".
`whoami` says `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1025960000`

When I run this image locally (`docker run something`) and then `docker exec -it 53c /bin/bash` it works as expected:
`dotnet-counters ps` displays the output
`whoami` says `root`

Documentation says

> To attach to a process, dotnet-counters requires that you are the same
>   user as the target process or the root user.

So I am assuming it doesn't work in Openshift because the terminal user is not root or target process user.

What I tried so far (please keep in mind I am not exactly good at linux systems):
Asked the Openshift team if I can run as root inside container. They just said no because security.
Then I tried modifying Dockerfile by adding this just before the ENTRYPOINT line.

```
USER 1025960000
```

I wanted to make the target process run under same user that I get when opening terminal. Because as far as I see terminal always opens with the same user. My assumtion was that if I run the application under same user as the terminal opens, then it would be allowed to run counters. But after trying this new image, `dotnet-counters ps` says 'Permission denied' ***both locally in Docker and in Openshift***. When I remote into local docker container however, `whoami` says `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1025960000`.

Then I tried modifying Dockerfile to create a custom user with known password and run the process using it

```
RUN useradd -m -p <hashed password> -s /bin/bash runtimeuser 
USER runtimeuser
```

And then I wanted to change user from default to this runtimeuser inside openshift terminal

```
$ su runtimeuser
Password: 
su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted
```

... I have exhaused my ideas on how to approach this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any _specific_ experience with dotnet, but here are some generic guidelines for creating images for OCP: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/openshift_images/create-images.html#images-create-guide-openshift_create-images. Also, when testing locally, be sure to specify a non-root user with `docker run -u 1001 -it`.

Comment: Which version of OCP do you use? 4.X or 3.X?

Comment: We are using OCP 3.11

Comment: I was wondering maybe the way I create user is somehow wrong? Maybe I need to set some groups etc?